# You do not have sufficient permissions to perform (FB like) action

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code:

```
public class LikeFbPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ImageButton mLockImage;
    Response fbServerResponse;

    public LikeFbPostAsyncTask(ImageButton lockImage) {
        mLockImage = lockImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("LikeFbPostAsyncTask", "Starting web task...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... fbPostId) {

        Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                fbPostId[0] + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                new Request.Callback() {

                    // here is non-ui thread
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                        fbServerResponse = response;

                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

}

for submitting FB like.

This is the request to FB server:

```
{Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_birthday, user_location, user_likes, user_interests, user_friends, user_status, basic_info]}, appId:1313----0364547}, graphPath: 685560152_10153987123125153/likes, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: POST, parameters: Bundle[{migration_bundle=fbsdk:20131203}]}
```

and I get the following error:

`errorMessage: (#200) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action`

How can i get a sufficient permission?

**update**
I have tried @serge solution

and added "users_like to app in Fb pgae under app center permissions

Now I get this error:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2000, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#2000) The publish_likes feature is disabled for this application.}, isFromCache:false}
```

Comment: You can check if your app been restricted by going to https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

Answer (score -1):

Under your app on [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com), go to **App Details** and click **Configure App Center Permissions**. Then make sure that you have corresponding permissions under **App Center Permissions**.

**updated:** I think you need to add **publish_likes** tag as well

Comment: I have added "users_like to app in Fb page under app center permissions

Now I get this error:

    {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2000, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#2000) The publish_likes feature is disabled for this application.}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: why do facebook force the developer to ask for "publish_actions" twice?  (1) in the FB session via java code and (2) in "App Center Permissions."

Comment: The App Center Permissions only matters if your app is in App Center. It doesn't matter at all otherwise

Comment: I think your comment doesn't apply since his app in the app center, I just need to investigate his new error..

Comment: I think you need to add publish_likes tag as well